# Can i add multiple LocalStorages in Jquery

Tags: jquery, web, local-storage

I am building a web app and i am using localstorage to save projects data in the browser, however i need a more efficient way than saving data to a million localStorage variables and assigning them like localStorage.save1 = el1,localStorage.save2 = el2, etc. I also need more than a total of 5 MB (which is the max of localStorage memory). Can each localStorage variable store 5 mb of data or all the LocalStorage variables together can only combine to a max of 5mb?

Comment: Afaik, localStorage memory limitation is as a whole.  Not individual variables.

Comment: Also, how much memory are we looking at, that your application "needs"?  A million variables sounds excessive.

Comment: i want to store around 100 projects data i(i'm doing this locally to for testing purposes right now). So definitely upwards of 50mb. SO around 100 variables